# Реализация хостинга нескольких служб WCF как один сервис?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, веб-служба

Добрый день, подскажите как можно реализовать несколько сервис контрактов на на одном сервисе, не используя частичные классы, и чтобы сервис не состоял с одного класса? а то сейчас мне приходится создавать 40 интересов которые наследует 1 класс.

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а вам зачем? Хорошая практика: один контракт = один сервис. Вы можете вынести реализацию методов в специализированные классы, и сократить код методов контрактов до одной строчки для вызова метода специализированного класса, но полностью избавиться от необходимости реализовать интерфейсы контрактов ни как не получится

Comment: Я хочу сделать много контрактов один сервис чтобы они были на одном базовом адресе, а не делать 40 сервисов)

Comment: Как хостится сервис?

Comment: IIS, на одном базовом адресе с https

Comment: ну так вы можете хостить кучу сервисов параллельно на одном базовом адресе. У каждой привязки же собственный суффикс для конечных точек контрактов. А базовый адрес может быть один.

Comment: То есть создать 40 сервисов и использовать один базовый адрес?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67546/discussion-between-rdorn-and-sergey-zavada).